# Scraping a web content executing an event but unexpected click event appeared

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So I am trying to make a get request, access the a web execute an event ( in this case press a button to extend a table and scrape the content.

This is my code:

```
def exec_func():

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.section-box.kurser-table-container")))

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@ng-click='listLengthMax = 3000']")

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

    element.click()
    return driver.page_source
```

However an ElementClickInterceptedError arised ! This seems to happen because  some other element obscures the element i am looking forward to click.

[This is the web I am interested in](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/markets-hub/assets/shares/)

How could I scrape the content of the table avoiding the issue with this blocking

Comment: you need to dismiss that overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

Option 1: scroll into view the element

```
def exec_func():

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.section-box.kurser-table-container")))

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@ng-click='listLengthMax = 3000']")
    element.location_once_scrolled_into_view #scroll into view the element first
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

    element.click()
    return driver.page_source
```

---

Option 2: Accept the cookie

```
def exec_func():

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    #accept the cookie
    wait.until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='sp_message_iframe_']")))
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Accept']"))).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    #=================================
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.section-box.kurser-table-container")))

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@ng-click='listLengthMax = 3000']")
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

    element.click()
    return driver.page_source
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def exec_func():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.telegraph.co.uk/markets-hub/assets/shares/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.section-box.kurser-table-container")))

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@ng-click='listLengthMax = 3000']")

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

    element.click()
    return driver.page_source

print(exec_func())
```